# Need help identifying old microcontroller from 1980's era digital instrument cluster

Tags: microcontroller, identification, automotive

I have a partially shorted digital instrument cluster from my car. I accidentally applied power with reversed polarity, when testing a new sensor I bought from a local group. Then the magic smoke appeared and the RPM display stopped working.

I'm having trouble identifying the IC. The marking says:

```
F145-7598  
(C) Intel`80
```

[image: Main microcontroller for my car's digital instrument cluster]

I'm trying to replace it with an Arduino NANO, but I don't know which pin does what. All I know is that this IC used to run the VFD tube display showing engine RPM.

No datasheet found anywhere, even from the car's Facebook community group. What is this chip actually? 8051? 8031? This board is from a 1988 Toyota Cressida.

Comment: Nippon Denso tended to use 8048 based micros. It wouldn’t surprise me if they went to 8051. Nevertheless, knowing the actual architecture won’t help you too much. It could have custom peripherals etc. i’d suggest you sketch out the schematic then use a cheapy logic analyser to determine the timing etc then mimic the operation in an Aruduino.

Comment: Given the date and package I'd guess it was based either on an 8051 or else an 8048 core. They were big on OTP fuse-ROM back then, too. It may use that. It's unlikely that the core was modified. I don't think the customer would have wanted to pay for it. So check the pinouts for those two families from Intel.  But that almost certainly has software in it and you don't have any of its specifications on hand, I bet. So I don't see a path from A to Z, here. What's your plan?

Comment: @Kartman If I buy a 8051 chip and install it in this board will it work or i have to copy the program from a known working chip?

Comment: Even if the pinout matches a generic 8051, it won't do anything useful without code in it.

Comment: @PutraAdriansyah If the board has ROM on it then it is possible that the program is on the board. (The 8051, for example, has a pin that can disable the internal ROM.) But the 8051 and 8048 processor cores were offered with ROM inside just for purposes such as this board. If you cannot find external ROM directly connected to that MCU, then the software is almost certain to be inside the chip. In that case, replacing it will be of no help. You'd need to access the ROM inside it and extract its details.

Comment: there are no external ROM spoldered. just a bunch of 40** logic IC (i have a photo: https://putranetwork.coffeecup.com/se/IC-2.jpeg )

Comment: Any kind of external ROM/EPROM from that era would probably be in at least a 32 pin package (16-bits address, 8 bits data, CE, RD, maybe OE, power & GND), and I don't see another package of that size in the picture.  Also, given the price pressure on the automotive market, I don't see why Toyota would chose a 2-chip solution rather than one.

Comment: @PutraAdriansyah Yeah. That means you face the problem of offloading the software in the MCU chip. It's probably 8k or less. They made several standard sizes available to customers, but this is an area where they would have readily added more or else reduced it per customer need.

Comment: if i want to replace it with arduino, i can just remove the chip and start experimenting by applying some signal to the pins?

Comment: @PutraAdriansyah Well, I don't think that would be wise. Although [some are saying](https://www.sens.org/about-us/general-faq/) that people alive today will be alive 1000 years from now, that activity could still manage to waste a substantial portion. If you are seriously motivated, you need to sit down and work through all the chips on that board and lay out a schematic. Then add where all the lines from the board go into the car. From that map, one can make some educated guesses. This would turn random hen-pecks into directed reverse-engineering. I've done things this way before.

Comment: @PutraAdriansyah Luckily for you, SMT wasn't a thing back then. Neither were 12-layer boards. Everything was designed for hand-soldering by the fumble-fingered and so that blue-wire fixes could be readily added afterwards on one side or the other. So big parts. Which means fewer of them. Lots fewer. Which means reverse-engineering won't be that hard to take on. You may want a bright light so you can see all the traces. Then Ohm them out to be sure of each.

Comment: I'll try that.. I think it will take time for me because I haven't done reverse engineering before :D

Comment: @PutraAdriansyah We all start at the same place of ignorance. It's just that some of us are more persistent than others. ;) But a need for something is a great motivator!

Comment: I've found this replacement [Toyota Cressida Instrument Cluster MX73 10/1984-08/1988](https://www.allcarpartsonline.com.au/toyota-cressida-instrument-cluster-mx73-10-1984-08), but I don't know if it includes the electronics at the back because the picture is only of the front. They are happy to answer questions though.

Comment: The @tim is wise.  You could spend months reverse engineering this.  Or find a replacement or go to a junk dealer.  Is this a good investment in your time?

Comment: @tim the cluster in the link is the analog one.. mine is a digital with no needle at all.. it uses VFD Tube (pre-LCD era) as the main display and i want to control the panel with Arduino to make some modernization to the car..

Comment: Some reverse engineering advice - start from what you know. ie from the power in and the rpm signal. It then becomes much like a jigsaw puzzle - you slowly piece it together. Basically all you need is a pencil, paper, multimeter with a beep function, the interwebs to look up the ic pinouts and some patience.

Comment: From the socket on the right (back view) or left (face/front view), there is pin 8 (the tach signal from electronic igniter module) and it goes to an IC which also, no datasheet... and then to a few resistors then the CPU/MCU.. but the smoke is from the CPU/MCU side... i will post a link to the image soon to make it easier to explain

Comment: Apart from the microcontroller, the ics in your photo have easily obtained datasheets. 4000 series cmos is generic.